# Generate url with different locale in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a controller with a redirect like this:

```
return $this->redirect(
        $this->generateUrl(
            'my_route', 
            array(
                'stuff1' => $stuff1,
                'stuff2' => $stuff2,  
            )
        )
    );
```

The route controller has the route defined for various languages:

```
my_route:
    locales:  { en: "/{stuff1}/{stuff2}", es: "/{stuff1}/{stuff2}" }
    defaults: { _controller: myBundle:Controller:my_route}
```

It always redirects to 'en'. How can I force to redirect it to 'es'?

Comment: have you tried adding an array key as  `'_locale' =>'es'` on the generateurl method's parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
return $this->redirect(
    $this->generateUrl(
        'my_route', 
        array(
            'stuff1' => $stuff1,
            'stuff2' => $stuff2,
            '_locale' => 'es',
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This solution worked, but using 'locale' instead of '_locale'.